# undefined reference Clion for c program

Tags: c, clion, undefined-reference

I'm using CLion, but when I try to run my struct.c file, it always gives me:

In function â€˜mainâ€™:

(file location) warning: passing argument 1 of â€˜displayAllEmployeesâ€™ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

```
 displayAllEmployees(employees,cnt);
                     ^~~~~~~~~
```

In file included from

note: expected â€˜PERSON ** {aka struct person **}â€™ but argument is of type â€˜PERSON * {aka struct person *}â€™

void displayAllEmployees(PERSON *employees[], int numberOfEmployees);

[100%] Linking C executable struct

In function `main':

undefined reference to `addEmployee'

undefined reference to `displayEmployee'

undefined reference to `displayAllEmployees'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

CMakeFiles/struct.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'struct' failed

make[3]: *** [struct] Error 1

CMakeFiles/Makefile2:178: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/struct.dir/all' failed

make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/struct.dir/all] Error 2

CMakeFiles/Makefile2:190: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/struct.dir/rule' failed

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/struct.dir/rule] Error 2

Makefile:157: recipe for target 'struct' failed

make: *** [struct] Error 2

I was hoping you guys could help me out. In the CMakeLists.txt I set the executable for person.c, and for struct.c separate. For the header file I initialized the functions, but whenever I try to run the struct.c file it always gives me the error.

Struct.c

```
    #include "person.h"

    int main(void)

    {
    int cnt;
    printf("How many employees? ");
    scanf("%d", &cnt);

    PERSON employees[cnt];

    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        PERSON employee;
        addEmployee(&employee);
        employees[i]= employee;
        printf("\n");
    }
    displayEmployee(&employees[0]);
    displayAllEmployees(employees,cnt);
    return 0;
}
```

person.c

```
    #include "person.h"
    #include <stdio.h>

    void addEmployee(PERSON *employee)

    {
    DATE mydate;
    printf("Enter info for next employee.\n");
    printf("Name : ");
    scanf("%s", employee->name);
    printf("Age : ");
    scanf("%d", &employee->age);
    printf("Height : ");
    scanf("f",&employee->height);

    printf("Enter DOB: ");
    printf("Enter month: ");
    scanf("%d", &mydate.month);
    printf("Enter day: ");
    scanf("%d", &mydate.day);
    printf("Enter your year: ");
    scanf("%d", &mydate.year);
    employee->birthday = mydate;

    }

    void displayEmployee(PERSON *employee)

    {
    printf("Name: %s\n", employee->name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", employee->age);
    printf("Height: .1%f\n", employee->height);
    printf("Birthday: %d/%d/%d", employee->birthday.month,employee->birthday.day,employee->birthday.year);

}

    void displayAllEmployees(PERSON *employees[], int numberOfEmployees)

    {
    for(int i=0; i< numberOfEmployees;i++)
    {
        displayEmployee(employees[i]);
        employees++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

person.h

```
#ifndef PERSON_H

#define PERSON_H

#include <stdio.h>

typedef char NAME[41];
typedef struct date

{
int month;
int day;
int year;
}DATE;
typedef struct person{
NAME name;
int age;
float height;
DATE birthday;
}PERSON;

void addEmployee(PERSON *employee);
void displayEmployee(PERSON *employee);
void displayAllEmployees(PERSON *employees[], int numberOfEmployees);


#endif //PERSON_H
```

CMAKE:

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(c_tut)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-m64 -g -O0 -D_DEBUG -Wall")

include_directories(AFTER src)

add_executable(person src/person.c)
add_executable(struct src/struct.c)

Comment: What's in `person.h`?

Comment: it wouldn't let me. It said it was too much code.

Comment: You say the errors are when "I run my struct.c file". Are they actually **compiler** errors, or **linker errors**? Please post the full error messages, in the question.

Comment: nevermind I just put it

Comment: I think it is a linker error, because when I put the functions in the struct.c file, the code runs perfect.

Comment: Should be `void displayAllEmployees(PERSON *employees, int numberOfEmployees)`. The way you have it is an array of pointers.

Comment: The three errors you originally posted are linker errors. The header file contains the three function prototypes, so there must be something wrong with the makefile, or the command you use to compile.

Comment: For the command the program automatically does it because I have WSL as the toolchain.